# Property *** does not exist on type 'ExoticComponent<any>

Tags: reactjs, next.js, code-splitting

I try to do code split in React / Next.js project, but facing with obstacles.

I am following the howto here: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Importing here:

```js
const { SHA512 } = React.lazy(() => import("crypto-js"));
```

and using in `useEffect` here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let window2: any = window;
      if (window2.bp && process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BARION_ID) {
        const { totalPriceInt, unitPriceInt } = calcUnitAndTotalPrice(
          startPaymentIn,
          buyTicketData
        );
        window2.bp("track", "initiateCheckout", {
          contentType: "Product",
          currency: "HUF",
          id: startPaymentIn.eventId,
          name: buyTicketData?.name,
          quantity: startPaymentIn.quantity ?? 1.0,
          unit: "db",
          imageUrl: `https://ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/${buyTicketData?.imgId}_0.cover.jpg`,
          list: "ProductPage",
        });
        window2.bp("track", "setUserProperties", {
          userId: SHA512(getTempUserId(localStorage)).toString(), // <--- HERE
        });
      }
    }, 4000);
  }, []);
```

but get this error:

```
./components/LoginAndRegistration.tsx:25:9
Type error: Property 'SHA512' does not exist on type 'ExoticComponent<any> & { readonly _result: ComponentType<any>; }'.

  23 | import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login";
  24 | import axios from "axios";
> 25 | const { SHA512 } = React.lazy(() => import("crypto-js"));
     |         ^
  26 | 
  27 | interface LoginAndRegistrationProps {
  28 |   isRegistration: boolean;
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Do you know maybe why it is wrong?

Before it worked without lazy loading:

```
import { SHA512 } from "crypto-js";
```

I also tryed Next.js workaround:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const { SHA512 } = dynamic(() => import("crypto-js"));
```

but got this error:

```
Type error: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

  130 | 
  131 |   useEffect(() => {
> 132 |     const { SHA512 } = await import("crypto-js");
      |                        ^
  133 |     setTimeout(() => {
  134 |       let window2: any = window;
  135 |       if (window2.bp && process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BARION_ID) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import("crypto-js")` returns a promise, that once resolved, has the API of the module. It's not a React component, hence you can't use `React.lazy()` on it. (You could use `React.lazy` with a module that exports a component.)

If you need to lazily load `crypto-js` within a React component, and then do things, you can do

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [cryptoJs, setCryptoJs] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => import("crypto-js").then(setCryptoJs), []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(!cryptoJs) return;  // not loaded yet...
    const { SHA512 } = cryptoJs;
    // ...
  }, [cryptoJs]);
}
```

or

```
function MyComponent() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    import("crypto-js").then(({ SHA512 }) => {
      // ...
    });
  }, []);
}
```

However, depending on your bundler and bundler configuration it might be better to just use a regular `import` for the library, and instead lazily import (e.g. with `React.lazy`) the module that has this component that requires the library.

Comment: Lazy load the component and not the module? For me it seems webpack - in my setting - is not enough smart, and if module is imported anywhere, it will download even if it is not used on a component at all.

Comment: I have an other issue here, but with icons, seems a bit similar, what do you think? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517872/how-to-load-icons-d%C3%ADnamicall-in-next-js

Comment: Importing a module could have side effects, so yes, a static import will pull in the module unless you tell Webpack the module is pure and doesn't have side effects.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy),

> `React.lazy` takes a function that must call a dynamic `import()`. This must return a `Promise` **which resolves to a module with a `default` export containing a React component**.

So you can't use `React.lazy` for the `crypto-js` package because it doesn't export a React component.

You can use [dynamic import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) in NextJS. As such:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  import('crypto-js').then(({ SHA512 }) => {
    // Use SHA512 here
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: `useEffect` functions can't be `async` due to the implicit return promise.

Comment: @AKX Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated the code.